# AWS CLI eb deploy not running migrations on new RDS mysql instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I'm creating a new application on AWS using the command line interface **EB CLI 3.5 (Python 2.7.2)**.  I run `eb init` and set my region and application name, and then `eb create`.

After running `eb create`, my environment builds and gives the error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'`. This makes perfect sense, there is no database since `eb create` only creates the EC2 instance, Autoscaling group, Cloudwatch alarms, Security groups etc.

I create an RDS instance via the web console -> software configuration page and add the connection env variables to my database.yml file:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

and run `eb deploy` again (no errors on deploy) but I get this error when I go to view the page:

`Mysql2::Error: Table 'DATABASE-NAME.users' doesn't exist` in the production log, I can verify this when I connect to the production database and there are no tables.

It appears that my migrations are not running when I run the `eb deploy` command.  Am I missing a link between creating the database via the web console and deploying via the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=213798) it now works for me. There seems to be an issue with the latest version of eb cli where it's setting `leader_only` to false so the rake task is not run on deployment.

The (hopefully temporary) solution is to set up a container_command to run the migration rake task.